# Basic mmap implementation

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, c

I am pretty much new to linux and am writing a custom driver for which I need to use mmap. I have found the sample code in many places as below

```
static int simple_remap_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vm->vm_pgoff,
                vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                vma->vm_page_prot))
        return -EAGAIN;

    vma->vm_ops = &simple_remap_vm_ops;
    simple_vma_open(vma);
    return 0;
}
```

But I want to know where exactly does this code specify which portion of kernel memory to map e.g if I have allocated a buffer in the kernel using kmalloc pointed to by *kptr how can i mmap that buffer to user space. Thank you.